# Can the object be used while it is being destructed in other thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, collections

I have 2 classes: `Object` and `Collection`. The `Collection` class stores pointers to `Object` instances. When `Object` is destructed, it removes itself from the collection.

The environment is multi-threaded. Objects and collections are protected by mutexes. The following situation is possible. The destructor of `Object` is called in one thread. Then context switch occurs to the second thread before the destructor of the object removes the object from the collection. The second thread can use the object because it is not removed from the collection yet.

I wonder if such behavior is valid. While the destructor is being called in one thread can the object be used in the second thread? Provided that the second thread is guaranteed to stop using the object before the destructor completes in the first thread.

It is certainly not valid to use the object after destruction. But is it valid to use the object during destruction?

If it is not, is it possible to create a class that removes its objects from the collection automatically on destruction?

Comment: If the object is protected by mutex, then during destruction is the mutex lock acquired? If yes, then how can collection access the object?

Comment: "The second thread can use the object because it is not removed from the collection yet" It seems a little dangerous to me, since conceptually the second thread are using a "half-destructed" object.

Comment: @kiner_shah, the context switch to the second thread can happen before mutex lock is aquired.

Comment: Also yes if you model shared ownership between the Collection and the thread. E.g. make a shared_ptr to the collection and when you start a thread using std::async (or std::thread) and a lambda that captures the shared_ptr by reference then the Collection will stay alive for as long as the thread needs access to it. (And same can be done for individual objects if needed)

Comment: Currently I use the following solution. I store `weak_ptr`s to the objects in the collection. `weak_ptr` expires before the object destructor is called, so there is no way to use the object when it is destructed. The destructor of the object asks the collection to remove expired `weak_ptr`s.